# efficient rbind alternative with applied function

Tags: r, image-processing

To take a step back, my ultimate goal is to read in around 130,000 images into R with a pixel size of HxW and then to make a dataframe/datatable containing the rgb of each pixel of each image on a new row. So the output will be something like this:

```
    > head(train_data, 10)
         image_no          r         g         b pixel_no
 1: 00003e153.jpg 0.11764706 0.1921569 0.3098039        1
 2: 00003e153.jpg 0.11372549 0.1882353 0.3058824        2
 3: 00003e153.jpg 0.10980392 0.1843137 0.3019608        3
 4: 00003e153.jpg 0.11764706 0.1921569 0.3098039        4
 5: 00003e153.jpg 0.12941176 0.2039216 0.3215686        5
 6: 00003e153.jpg 0.13333333 0.2078431 0.3254902        6
 7: 00003e153.jpg 0.12549020 0.2000000 0.3176471        7
 8: 00003e153.jpg 0.11764706 0.1921569 0.3098039        8
 9: 00003e153.jpg 0.09803922 0.1725490 0.2901961        9
10: 00003e153.jpg 0.11372549 0.1882353 0.3058824       10
```

I currently have a piece of code to do this in which I apply a function to get the rgb for each pixel of a specified image, returning the result in a dataframe:

```
#function to get rgb from image file paths
get_rgb_table <- function(link){

  img <- readJPEG(toString(link))

  # Creating the data frame
  rgb_image <- data.frame(r = as.vector(img[1:H, 1:W, 1]),
                          g = as.vector(img[1:H, 1:W, 2]),
                          b = as.vector(img[1:H, 1:W, 3]))
  #add pixel id
  rgb_image$pixel_no <- row.names(rgb_image)

  #add image id
  train_rgb <- cbind(sub('.*/', '',link),rgb_image)
  colnames(train_rgb)[1] <- "image_no"
  return(train_rgb)
}
```

I call this function on another dataframe which contains the links to all the images:

```
train_files <- list.files(path="~/images/", pattern=".jpg",all.files=T, full.names=T, no.. = T)
train <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(train_files), nrow=length(train_files), byrow=T))
```

The train dataframe looks like this:

```
> head(train, 10)
                               link
1  C:/Documents/image/00003e153.jpg
2  C:/Documents/image/000155de5.jpg
3  C:/Documents/image/00021ddc3.jpg
4  C:/Documents/image/0002756f7.jpg
5  C:/Documents/image/0002d0f32.jpg
6  C:/Documents/image/000303d4d.jpg
7  C:/Documents/image/00031f145.jpg
8  C:/Documents/image/00053c6ba.jpg
9  C:/Documents/image/00057a50d.jpg
10 C:/Documents/image/0005d01c8.jpg
```

I finally get the result I want with the following loop:

```
for(i in 1:length(train[,1])){
  train_data <- rbind(train_data,get_rgb_table(train[i,1]))
}
```

However, this last bit of code is very inefficient. An optimization of how the function is applied and and/or the rbind would help. I think the function `get_rgb_table()` itself is quick but the problem is with the loop and the rbind. I have tried using `apply()` but can't manage to do this on each row and put the result in one dataframe without running out of memory. Any help on this would be great. Thanks!

Comment: You don't say what your function does nor what your input and output data looks like. It's very difficult for people to help.. Are you trying to only optimize the `rbind` part or also the "apply a function to every row of a dataframe" part?

Comment: `data.table::rbindlist()` should be much faster, but this seems like a questionable process to begin with, looping over the data.frame, there may be a better way.

Comment: I think @avid_useR suggested explaining what the function does because as often times there's a more efficient solution than applying the function to each row.

Comment: Growing things in R is usually bad, especially for data frames, since it's very slow and memory inefficient. If you know how many rows the result should have beforehand, you can start a data frame with that size and fill it with results generated by the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Moses I’ll try that too and see!

Comment: I have updated my question to hopefully be more clear, I am sorry this was not done from the outset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very difficult to answer given the vagueness of the question, but I'll make a reproducible example of what I *think* you're asking and will give a solution.

Say I have a function that returns a data frame:

```
MyFun <- function(x)randu[1:x,]
```

And I have a data frame `df` that will act an input to the function.

```
#     a  b
# 1   1 21
# 2   2 22
# 3   3 23
# 4   4 24
# 5   5 25
# 6   6 26
# 7   7 27
# 8   8 28
# 9   9 29
# 10 10 30
```

From your question, it looks like only one column will be used as input. So, I apply the function to each row of this data frame using `lapply` then I bind the results together using `do.call` and `rbind` like this:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(df$a, MyFun))
```

Comment: Constructive criticism appreciated if you could clarify the downvote.